# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment no longer exists for key f0: index 1

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having couple of fragment in an Activity. After doing some process I am closing the fragment using the below code.

```
if (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

But on line popBackStackImmediate() its throwing the error

```
    Process: com.TestProject.testpro, PID: 17966
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment no longer exists for key f0: index 1
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:879)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:215)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1481)
     at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:14746)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3121)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3127)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3127)
     at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:14724)
     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:475)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1329)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executePopOps(BackStackRecord.java:807)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2360)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:823)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:776)
     at com.TestProject.testpro.application.fragments.WFMUpgradeToAffinityFragmentAN$WFMStoreProfileIdReceiver.onReceive(WFMUpgradeToAffinityFragmentAN.java:1064)
     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

There is no other crash which close the fragment. I cant find the exact solution for this issue. Please help me on this.

Edited:

I am using the below function to call the fragment.

```
void showContentFragment(Fragment newFragment, String backStackName) {
    //Log.e(TAG, "showContentFragment- " + "BackstackName: "+ backStackName);
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (newFragment != null) {
        //updateNavigation(backStackName);
        FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        if (backStackName != null && !backStackName.isEmpty()) {
            ft.addToBackStack(backStackName);
        }

        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using just `popBackStack()` ?

Comment: @Kiya Yes I have tried. Still no luck.

Comment: Are you adding your fragment to backstack? Please post your code where you add your fragment in the activity.

Comment: And why do you need to do this manually? getActivity().onBackPressed() should be more than sufficient to go back to the previous fragment, in case you are doing it properly.

Comment: @Sniper Did you fixed this issue?

Comment: @Sniper Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 25):

For ViewPager2 simply use `viewPager.setSaveEnabled(false);`

Comment: Yes, it works, I think, it was gotten from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486504/fragment-no-longer-exists-for-key-fragmentstateadapter-with-viewpager2.

Answer (score 2):

In the ViewPager Adapter, override `restoreState(state, loader)`

```
    @Override
    public void restoreState(final Parcelable state, final ClassLoader loader) {
        try {
            super.restoreState(state, loader);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately, this will not work for ViewPager2. restoreState is declared as final.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this steps to add fragments from your activity

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame, yourFragment, yourFragment.class.getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(yourFragment.class.getSimpleName())
                .commit();
```

using this code for calling `popBackStack()` from your fragment

```
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Make sure that you are importing right fragment class

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: I am following the same steps mentioned above. Still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

add Below code in your Fragment classes , according to [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getReturnTransition()) it returns the Transition to use to move Views out of the Scene when the Fragment is preparing to close.

```
@Override
    public Object getReturnTransition() {
        return super.getReturnTransition();
    }
```

Comment: Added this too. Its still crashing.

Comment: Yes. Same crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your stacktrace shows you are using both a `ViewPager` and manipulating the backstack yourself.

This is probably not a good idea - either let your `ViewPager` manage the backstack (which it does well) or manage it entirely yourself.

Note that in managing the backstack yourself you will have to account for restoring instance state (which features in your stacktrace) and the [Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle).

This means in conditions of low memory your Activity and Fragments will be stopped. If you have not saved the instance state correctly, when they are restarted you will get errors like the above one. If the workflow of your Fragments is simple, you can avoid all of this by using a `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void showContentFragment(Fragment fragment, Bundle bundle, boolean addToBackStack) {
        if (bundle != null)
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        tag = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        ft.replace(R.id.container_internal, fragment, tag);
        fragment.setRetainInstance(true); // IMPORTANT

        if (addToBackStack)
            ft.addToBackStack(tag);

        try {
            ft.commit();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to call `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`. `getFragmentManager()` is enough to call `FragmentManager`.

If you are in **Support Fragment** getFragmentManager() will give you `supportFragmentManager()` or it will give you **app.Fragment Manager**.

If you are calling the PopBackstack inside the ViewPager, it won't work. If you are using `viewPager` inside another fragment. you should call `popBackstack` only in the parent fragment. Not in the `viewPager`.

Try the below code it will clear the stack according to the back stack name.

```
getFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(YourBackStackName, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
```

Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStackImmediate(java.lang.String, int)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Overriding restoreState method in my viewPager worked for me.

```
override fun restoreState(state: Parcelable?, loader: ClassLoader?) {
        try {
            super.restoreState(state, loader)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Here is the final code of my view pager

```
class MenuTabAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    private val mFragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
    private val mFragmentTitleList = ArrayList<String>()
    private var mCurrentPosition = -1
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return mFragmentList[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mFragmentList.size
    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment)
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return mFragmentTitleList[position]
    }

    override fun setPrimaryItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, `object`)


        if (position !== mCurrentPosition && container is HeightWrappingViewPager) {
            val fragment = `object` as Fragment
            if (fragment?.view != null) {
                mCurrentPosition = position
                container.requestLayout()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun restoreState(state: Parcelable?, loader: ClassLoader?) {
        try {
            super.restoreState(state, loader)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### When this crash occurs?

- When ViewPager wraps Fragment, and there is ViewPager wraps Fragment inside Fragment.
- When the outer Fragment or the inner Adapter inherits FragmentStatePagerAdapter, or both inherit FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

### How to fix?

Override the following method in the Adapter of the Fragment that reported the error and return null.

```
@Override  
public Parcelable saveState() {  
    return null;  
}
```

More details [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/66246765751/).

Answer (score 0):

This happens when `viewPagerAdapter`(in ViewPager2->restorePendingState->restoreState) became null, but ViewPager2->restorePendingState still received it.

Try to mark stop breakpoint at this line or reinstall app

*void is in androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2*

```
private void restorePendingState() {
    ...
    Adapter<?> adapter = getAdapter();
    if (adapter == null) {
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```