# Fragment no longer exists for key FragmentStateAdapter with Viewpager2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, fragmentstatepageradapter, android-viewpager2

I am using ViewPager2 for my project. I need to use nested fragments inside a fragment with viewpager2. it works like charm until I try to navigate between fragments(not nested ones).

After the first time navigating between fragments, the application crash with the error explained below.

the fragment which contains nested fragments OnCreateView method:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.orders_fragment, null);

ViewPager2 viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.childViewPager);

TabLayout tabs = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),getLifecycle());

viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);

TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy tabConfigurationStrategy = (tab, position) -> {

    String[] order_activity_tabs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.situations);

    for (int i=0; i<order_activity_tabs.length; i++) {

        if(i==position)
            tab.setText(order_activity_tabs[i]);

    }
};

TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewPager, tabConfigurationStrategy);
tabLayoutMediator.attach();

return view;
```

When I return the fragment that contains nested fragments it crashes with

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment no longer exists for key f#0: unique id 4fbe17b8-5e22-4e07-a543-4a79445ad39c
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java:365)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStateAdapter.java:549)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.restorePendingState(ViewPager2.java:350)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager2.java:375)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4045)
        at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:20253)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:548)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:907)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
```

There are solutions for FragmentStatePagerAdapter but there is no for FragmentStateAdapter. And because I can't override methods in FragmentStateAdapter, implementing this solutions are impossible.

Thank you for reading this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: before you access fragment first check it is present or not in fragment stack.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am not sure to how to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using viewpager2 with `FragmentStateAdapter` has a similar behaviour than `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Actually there are two ways of solving this problem

First one is seting `setSaveEnabled()` to false into our viewpager2

```
viewpager2.setSaveEnabled(false)
```

The other one is overriding `restoreState` at our adapter and return null

Check : https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter

### Important

Please note that this should not be the recommended way of disabling the state, this should work for some use cases but for production apps consider saving the state of the fragment or re-emiting the state to the UI from a state holder like viewmodel

Comment: unfortunately, restoreState is declared as final

Comment: I'm surprised about the number of up votes of this answer.

1. If you do that the app is not able to save and recreate the state of the previous fragment.
2. As @JE42 said the `restoreState` is delcared as final.

Comment: I think that its more fore debugging purposes rather than replacing the saving state of the fragment

Comment: it's not recommended to do this in the product version, no state will be saved for this view if you set it to false and it means when you come back from another screen to a fragment that has a view-pager, it will lose its previous data.

Comment: I totally agree @imansdn I think this is more of a quick work-around , but as you said it should never be used for production apps if we want to preserve the state. I think that we are able to change the state by ourselves for some use cases, because I don't see any purpose from the framework if they let us change this.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with viewpager2 detach from recyclerview
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154751401

As per my knowledge two fixes are there:

1. add this line in your xml viewpager2 component.

   ```
   android:saveEnabled="false"
   ```

But the above one don't restore the current instance, which the fragment will recreate each time it popsBack.

2. The recommended solution is add the below line on your fragment

   ```
   override fun onDestroyView() {
      super.onDestroyView()
      binding.pager.adapter = null
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you explain why the recommended solution works?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to set your viewpager2 in the layout file with the following property

```
android:saveEnabled="true"
```

Comment: Shouldn't the value set to "false" instead?

Answer (score 0):

try to call requireActivity() in your fragment argument inside FragmentStateAdapter

```
private inner class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fa: FavoriteFragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fa.requireActivity())
```

Answer (score -2):

I just had the same issue. The cause is that when the containing fragment is recreated, it's childFragmentManager is as well. And the FragmentStateAdapter looks in the passed fragmentmanager to find fragments it restores state for.

My solution was to have it use the activity's fragmentManager instead of the fragment's, for example use the constructor that takes an activity like

```
class MyAdapter(f: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(f.activity!!)
```

or when using the `FragmentStateAdapter(FragmentManager, Lifecycle)` constructor, make sure to pass `parentFragmentManager` and **not** childFragmentManager

Answer (score -3):

My problem solved with implementing new Navigation Component. It itself handles fragment transition. Anyone who across with this problem can change their navigation method.

Comment: could you please explain more your solution?